# Create PDF not working in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

Please help me because I'm not able to create a PDF in Laravel 5.2.

**Details:**

My `composer.json` file

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "laravel/socialite": "^2.0",
        "tzsk/payu": "^1.2",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.6.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

I have tried to installed the version 0.6.1 of `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`

Once we run : this command :-

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```

Result :
    Using version 0.6.1 for barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
    ./composer.json has been updated
    loading composer repositories with package information
    updating dependencies (including require-dev)
    nothing to installing and update

Then I tried to run the command: `composer update`, with the following output:

```
loading composer repositories with package information  
updating dependencies (including require-dev)
nothing to installing and update
problem 1: this package require php>=5.5.9 but your PHP version (5.4.45) does not satisfy that require
```

Comment: use mPdf https://packagist.org/packages/mpdf/mpdf and try to upgrade php version

Comment: Thanks Ajay Deepak kumar  for answering , is there any other solution without update php version ? , i have also tried dompdf/dompdf but not working showing same problem .

Comment: Deepak , please let me know , how to use the mpdf in laravel 5.2

Comment: Finally woking here is code i am using mpdf package in laravel 5.2  require_once  '/home/projectFolder/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/mpdf.php';
           $mpdf = new \mPDF();
 $mpdf->WriteHTML('<h1>Hello deepak goud</h1>');
           $mpdf->Output();

Comment: have a look on answer

Comment: Dude, your Php is too old if you haven't already noticed

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add mPDF in your project using composer
run this via terminal or your preferred 
`composer require mpdf/mpdf`

Documentation :- https://mpdf.github.io/

you can create pdf like this

```
class PdfController extends Controller
{
    // #example 1
    public function createPdf($name = 'pdf'){

        require_once '../vendor/mpdf/mpdf/mpdf.php';

        $mpdf = new \mPDF();
        $mpdf->WriteHTML(view('view.path..', ['data' => $data]));
        $mpdf->Output($name.'.pdf','I'); // this will output data
    }


    // #example 2
    // this will create fullpage pdf your can customize 
    public function createPdf($name = 'pdf', $html = ''){

        require_once '../vendor/mpdf/mpdf/mpdf.php';

        $mpdf = new \mPDF ('utf-8', 'Letter', 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

        $mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;  // 1 or 0 - whether to indent the first level of a list

        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
        $mpdf->Output($name.'.pdf','I');
    }

}
```